# Disable username and password login in ASP.NET MVC 4 without disabling OAuth?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have login via OAuth already set up in ASP.NET MVC 4, using the built-in Individual User Accounts authentication method. Is there a way that I can disable login with a username and password, so that people can only login via one of the OAuth providers?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the code in the View that shows the local login form.